# What kind of permissions required to send an email to Distribution List email ID in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Do we need any permissions to send an email notification across the Distribution List email ID from CRM.

Please suggest

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are running on-prem or online. If you have an email router (onprem) then in the email router configuration application you can set users to have outgoing and ingoing emails...I dont really understand your question though

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. We got the resolution for this, actually mail box is restricted outside domains that is the reason why we were not able to send an email.